# updating error during the upgrade of Quickblox sdk from 3.3.5 to 3.4.1

Tags: java, sdk, quickblox, quickblox-android, q-municate

I modified q-municate application android which is on open source on GitHub by QuickBlox.
Before the android sdk was 3.3.5. Now, i upgrade to 3.3.5 to 3.4.1.
after, doing the upgrade of sdk; i am getting this error. Please help me how to solve this issue.

Full Error Details:

Information:Gradle tasks [:q-municate_auth_service:generateDebugSources, :q-municate_auth_service:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :q-municate_auth_service:mockableAndroidJar, :q-municate_auth_service:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :Q-municate_db:generateDebugSources, :Q-municate_db:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :Q-municate_db:mockableAndroidJar, :Q-municate_db:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :Q-municate_core:generateDebugSources, :Q-municate_core:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :Q-municate_core:mockableAndroidJar, :Q-municate_core:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :Q-municate_app:generateDevDebugSources, :Q-municate_app:generateDevDebugAndroidTestSources, :Q-municate_app:prepareDevDebugUnitTestDependencies, :Q-municate_app:mockableAndroidJar, :q-municate_base_cache:generateDebugSources, :q-municate_base_cache:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :q-municate_base_cache:mockableAndroidJar, :q-municate_base_cache:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :q-municate_user_cache:generateDebugSources, :q-municate_user_cache:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :q-municate_user_cache:mockableAndroidJar, :q-municate_user_cache:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :q-municate_base_service:generateDebugSources, :q-municate_base_service:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :q-municate_base_service:mockableAndroidJar, :q-municate_base_service:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :q-municate_user_service:generateDebugSources, :q-municate_user_service:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :q-municate_user_service:mockableAndroidJar, :q-municate_user_service:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

Error:Execution failed for task ':Q-municate_app:processDevDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

Answer (score 0):

check your code and use same version for all libs of group 'com.android.support', in your case it will be 26.1.0.

Comment: i have done this but still not going to successfully update.

Comment: @is2017 it means, you checked not all dependencies, please follow this link for resolving your issue https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android/issues/250

Comment: did you try solution as I wrote in previous comment? And note: 07.12.2017 QB team released Q-municate with latest SDK version (3.5.2).